# Pylint ignore specific names

Tags: python, pylint

I have a problem with pylint, i.e. sometimes it repeats the same message for some variable/class/module etc. and I can't find a workaround for that. What I want is to say pylint
"don't check [message XXX|any message] for variable YYY in [this module|module "ZZZ"]" with some option or rcfile directive.

Comment: You can ignore all `pylint` checks for the specific variable via the `dummy-variables` configuration: stackoverflow.com/a/50118061/1814353

Comment: Maybe you mean `# pylint: disable=invalid-name` in the affected class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported in the current version of Pylint.

You may want to get in touch with the maintainers and propose them a feature request and an implementation.

Comment: Doesn't [`good-names`](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker) fit the bill quite well?

Answer (score 8):

There's [`good-names=YYY`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker-options) for this, or for some advanced stuff you can modify the regex via `variable-rgx`.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual) you enable and disable messages using lines like:

```
# pylint: disable=W0631
```

in the python code.

Comment: I know this feature, but i meant something like this
`# pylint: disable-msg=W0631 for variable foo`
in the beginning of the file

Comment: Rather `# pylint: disable=W0631`  in the lines with the var.

Comment: `for i in foo: # pylint: disable=W0631` works only for the line.