# How to disable pylint 'Undefined variable' error for a specific variable in a file?

Tags: python, pylint

I am hosting IronPython inside a C# application and injecting an API for the host into the global scope.

I have just started to love `syntastic` for vim with `pylint` for checking my scripts. But I am getting annoyed by all the `[E0602, method_name] Undefined variable 'variable_name'` error messages for the injected variables.

I am aware of using `# pylint: disable=E0602` to disable this error message, but I'd prefer not to cripple a really useful feature just for some specific variable names.

How do you deal with this?

Currently, I am doing this at the top of my script:

```
try:
    host_object = getattr(__builtins__, 'host_object')
except AttributeError:
    pass # oops, run this script inside the host application!!
```

What I would really like to do is this:

```
# pylint: declare=host_object, other_stuff
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233867/pylint-ignore-specific-names)?

Comment: quite possibly... except that question didn't get any good answers. I think @sthenault has a nice pointer here. We just need to fix his answer to include a link to the rc file documentation and maybe an example. But it looks like it could work!

Comment: @DarenThomas Did one of the answers here work, or did you find another solution?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, more or less. It seems you can't really do this, except per line or in a global file. I'd prefer not to accept any solution just yet, but have upvoted them all.

Comment: I think I read somewhere in the docs that a `# pylint: ...` is supposed to act scope-wide, so at the top of a module it should work unless that's false memory or a bug...

Comment: You can ignore all `pylint` checks for the specific variable via the `dummy-variables` configuration: stackoverflow.com/a/50118061/1814353

Answer (score 13):

You can add your variables to the 'additional-builtins' option so pylint will consider them as defined.

This has to be done in a rc file, it can't be done inlined in the code.

Answer (score 11):

Disabling E0602 in the code:

```
# make pylint think that it knows about 'injected_var' variable
injected_var = injected_var  # pylint:disable=invalid-name,used-before-assignment
```

Obviously, that needs to be done once per module, all occurrences of `injected_var` after this line would be legal for pylint.

Comment: Can't you just use `injected_var = None`?

Comment: @jamesdlin, "injected" in this question means a variable passed from some external context. Example: in the Zope debug session all executed code inherits a variable `app` which points to the ZODB tree root. Setting such variable to `None` would overwrite the value passed from the host application.

Comment: Great idea. I used # noqa instead, so neither Pylint nor flake8 will complain

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a **way to disable pylint argues about the specific undefined variable(s)** by specifying it in [dummy-variables-rgx](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html#id17) (or [dummy-variables](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-have-a-callback-function-where-i-have-no-control-over-received-arguments-how-do-i-avoid-getting-unused-argument-warnings) in the older `pylint` versions).
`dummy-variables` contain `_,dummy` by default and overwritten with the user-specified values on `pylint` execution:

```
$ pylint --dummy-variables-rgx='(_+[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$)|dummy|host_object'
```

or for the older `pylint` versions:

```
$ pylint --dummy-variables='_,dummy,host_object'
```

Or in case of the `pylint` configuration for [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (`User/Workspace Settings` can be opened by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--dummy-variables-rgx='(_+[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$)|dummy|qdict'"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's [`good-names=host_object,other_stuff`](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker) or [`additional-builtins=...`](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#variables-checker) for this, or for some advanced stuff you can modify the regex via [`variable-rgx`](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker).

Answer (score 2):

Not for variables, but you can disable it for the lines that have the var. See the [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233867/pylint-ignore-specific-names).

Comment: Actually, it is possible to disable `pylint` for the specific variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118061/1814353

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue and I just added disable options in pylintrc file. In my case, I am working on a small script and some of pylint checks are a bit overkill. So I disabled Undefined Variable Error

```
E: 32,40: Undefined variable 'description' (undefined-variable)
```

by

disable=E0602, E0603

You can find the codes and meaning at: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

My pylintrc file:

```
# The format of this file isn't really documented; just use --generate-rcfile
[MASTER]
# Add <file or directory> to the black list. It should be a base name, not a
# path. You may set this option multiple times.
#
# dirname, then we'll need to expand the ignore features in pylint :/
ignore=.git,tools, etc
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
# NOTE(gus): This is a long list.  A number of these are important and
# should be re-enabled once the offending code is fixed (or marked
# with a local disable)
disable=E0602, E0603,
# "F" Fatal errors that prevent further processing
 import-error,
# "I" Informational noise
 locally-disabled,
# "E" Error for important programming issues (likely bugs)
 access-member-before-definition,
 no-member,
 no-method-argument,
 no-self-argument,
# "W" Warnings for stylistic problems or minor programming issues
 abstract-method,
 arguments-differ,
 attribute-defined-outside-init,
 bad-builtin,
 bad-indentation,
 broad-except,
 dangerous-default-value,
 deprecated-lambda,
 deprecated-module,
 duplicate-key,
 expression-not-assigned,
 fixme,
 global-statement,
 no-init,
 non-parent-init-called,
 not-callable,
 protected-access,
 redefined-builtin,
 redefined-outer-name,
 signature-differs,
 star-args,
 super-init-not-called,
 super-on-old-class,
 unpacking-non-sequence,
 unused-argument,
 unused-import,
# "C" Coding convention violations
 invalid-name,
 missing-docstring,
 superfluous-parens,
 bad-continuation,
 Undefined variable,
# "R" Refactor recommendations
 abstract-class-little-used,
 abstract-class-not-used,
 duplicate-code,
 interface-not-implemented,
 no-self-use,
 too-few-public-methods,
 too-many-ancestors,
 too-many-arguments,
 too-many-branches,
 too-many-instance-attributes,
 too-many-lines,
 too-many-locals,
 too-many-public-methods,
 too-many-return-statements,
 too-many-statements


[BASIC]
# Variable names can be 1 to 31 characters long, with lowercase and underscores
variable-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}$

# Argument names can be 2 to 31 characters long, with lowercase and underscores
argument-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1,30}$

# Method names should be at least 3 characters long
# and be lowecased with underscores
method-rgx=([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,}|setUp|tearDown)$

# Module names matching vulcan-* are ok (files in bin/)
# module-rgx=(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(vulcan-[a-z0-9_-]+))$
module-rgx=(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([a-z0-9_-]+))$



# Don't require docstrings on tests.
no-docstring-rgx=((__.*__)|([tT]est.*)|setUp|tearDown)$

[FORMAT]
# Maximum number of characters on a single line.
max-line-length=79

[VARIABLES]
# List of additional names supposed to be defined in builtins. Remember that
# you should avoid to define new builtins when possible.
# _ is used by our localization
additional-builtins=_

[CLASSES]
# List of interface methods to ignore, separated by a comma.
ignore-iface-methods=

[IMPORTS]
# Deprecated modules which should not be used, separated by a comma
deprecated-modules=
# should use openstack.common.jsonutils
 json

[TYPECHECK]
# List of module names for which member attributes should not be checked
ignored-modules=six.moves,_MovedItems

[REPORTS]
# Tells whether to display a full report or only the messages
reports=no
```

Answer (score 1):

Stick this at the end of the line and you're done:

```
# noqa
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dummy-variables-rgx` didn't do the trick for me. I was having issues with a package which is only available on a cluster, and not when developing locally. I had to use the "additional-builtins" setting, and added this to my .pylintrc.

```
additional-builtins: mssparkutils
```