# Python: Undefined variable: 'snakemake', ignore warning, or ideally autocomplete for real

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm using [Snakemake](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake) and it's been rather enjoyable, but I would love it if VSCode stopped complaining about `Undefined variable: 'snakemake'`.  The issue is that Snakemake runs jobs in such a way that it injects this global into your python scope, but IDEs have no idea that it really *is* defined.  I am wondering if there is a way to get it to do two things:

1. Stop complaining, at the least
2. Do autocomplete--it should autocomplete based on the rules defined in the `Snakefile` (input, output, params, etc.) and its own APIs.

[image: Undefined variable: 'snakemake']

The VSCode extension for Snakemake only relates to the Snakefile syntax.  Elsewhere VSCode uses pylint.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `global snakemake` to tell Python it's supposed to pull from the global scope? I'd be wary of any tool that uses globals like this in Python, though; "explicit is better than implicit" is a pretty good general rule. Also, please post code as text in a code block rather than as an image.

Comment: Unfortunately, declaring it as a global doesn't do anything since it's still undefined, unless I'm misunderstanding your idea.

As for the image: I didn't think this code was important, it was more important to see how VSCode shows it is an error, but I can see how it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Only slightly better than [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577045/3476750) is to do:

```py
smk = snakemake # type: ignore
mlp = load_python_obj(smk.input.mlp_model_filename)
```

This inlines the exclusion to that one line (where `snakemake` is undefined), but allows the definition of `smk` so that when when you refer to `smk` there is no complaint. This allows other relevant cases of undefined variables to still be identified rather than excluding all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible solution, but thus far the only one that I have managed to find. I hope that this non-solution can be quickly supplanted by a better one.

At the top of the script file you can add

```
# pyright: reportUndefinedVariable=false
```

This removes the warning (and all other undefined variable warnings). If you have flake8 as well, you will have to use `# noqa: F821` on each line as well.

Comment: Is there a way to have both `type: ignore` for pylint and `noqa: F821` for flake8 at the same time.  Superlinter makes both complaints and I can't seem to quiet both.  It's either one or the other...  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

This won't remove the error, but it will disable all error messages.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-P and type `disable error messages` in the top. Click that and they will completely disappear (it won't fix the errors though)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work for you since your warning seems to come from python itself and not pylint (which was the case for me), but I just found a solution that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50118061/20667867).

I added to my pylint settings the following argument:

```
"--dummy-variables-rgx='(_+[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$)|dummy|snakemake'"
```

To do so, you can access your settings with <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>, search for "pylint:Args" and click on `Add Item`.

Basically, "(_+[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$)|dummy" is the default regex for the dummy variables (ignored by pylint) and by adding "snakemake" to it, this variable name doesn't produce pylint warnings anymore.