# Mark specific variables as known

Tags: python, pylint, static-code-analysis

I am developing Python scripts which run inside a Jython interpreter. This interpreter sets certain global variables, which I use inside the script.

Pylint of course does not know these variables, so it reports errors all over the place.

Is there a way of making pylint aware that there are certain variables defined outside of its scope?

Alternatively, is there a way that I can define the unknown variables to pylint?

I tried something like

```
if not globals().has_key('SOME_EXTERNAL_GLOBAL'):
    globals()['SOME_EXTERNAL_GLOBAL'] = None
```

But that did not help (pylint seems to ignore black magic done to globals()).

Comment: Is it reporting errors or warnings?

Comment: @njzk2: "known" variables = variables that I know are available globally due to some magic (done by the Jython interpreter).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I get errors (E0602)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

- add variable names to [additional-builtins](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id6)

> additional-builtins:
>
> List of additional names supposed to be
>   defined in builtins. Remember that you should avoid to define new
>   builtins when possible.

- add `# pylint: disable=E0602` comment on top of the file to disable `undefined-variable` check in the file
- add `# pylint: disable=E0602` comment in the code where the variable is used
- run pylint with `--disable-msg=E0602` option

Also see:

- [Pylint ignore specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233867/pylint-ignore-specific-names)
- [Howto ignore specific undefined variables in Pydev Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777880/howto-ignore-specific-undefined-variables-in-pydev-eclipse)
- [How to disable pylint 'Undefined variable' error for a specific variable in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088938/how-to-disable-pylint-undefined-variable-error-for-a-specific-variable-in-a-fi)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like all of these have to be done in the rc file (rather than inline in the code)...

Comment: There's also [`good-names`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker-options)